# Finding the eigenvector of a matrix using another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$, and $B$ be two matrices such that $B=A^{12}-8A^7+5A^5+4I_{3}$.

I'm asked to find two linearly-independent eigenvectors of $B$, and I'm only given the matrix $A$.
I have calculated that the eigenspace of $A$ for its eigenvalues $λ_{1}=2$,  $λ_{2}=3$, which are

$V(2)={x_{1}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}},$

$V(3)=x_{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$

where $x_{1}, x_{2} \in R$.

I know that the eigenvectors of matrix $B$ are the same as those of $A$. So two linear independent eigenvectors of $B$ would be any two vectors chosen one from $V(2)$ and one from $V(3)$, but how do I prove so?

Comment: Hint: $B$ commutes with $A$. Or just diagonalize.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Calculate

$$Bv=?$$

where $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, *i.e.* $Av=\lambda v$ (note that also $A^{n}v=\lambda^{n} v$). As for the linearity independence, note that this has nothing to do with the matrices. It is a property of set of vectors.

Comment: So would this be correct?

$(A^12-8A^7+5A^5+4I)x=(λ^8λ^7+5λ^5+4)χ$
solving for $λ_{1}=2$

$(A^12-8A^7+5A^5+4I)x_{1}=(2^{12}-8*2^7+5*2^5+4)x_{1}$

and then solving for $λ_{2}$.

Is this sufficient to prove that the eigenspaces of A and B are the same?

Comment: @VakiPitsi The whole point is that you don't need to calculate $B$ or solve for $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$, the eigenvectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(1,-1,1)$ that you've found are already good enough.

Answer (score 2):

If $p\in K[x], p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$, ($K$ is a field - here it is $\mathbb R$): take an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ and a corresponding eigenvector $x\ne 0$: $Ax=\lambda x$. Now, let $B=p(A)$. You have $Bx=(\sum_{i=0}^na_iA^i)x=\sum_{i=0}^na_i\lambda^ix=p(\lambda)x$, so $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ for the eigenvalue $p(\lambda)$.

In your case, $p(x)=x^{12}-8x^7+5x^5+4$.

Note: This is the proof that eigenvectors of $A$ are eigenvectors of $B$. The opposite is not necessarily true, $B$ may have additional eigenvectors.